# mysql 5.6 default location for my.cf on centos 5.2

Tags: mysql, rdbms

Mysql 5.6

tuning parameters are to be placed in /etc/mysql/my.cnf or of /etc/my.cnf depends on the Linux distro? If it is then please someone can guide for CentOS which my.cnf is essential?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The location of the my.cnf is configured at build time, so unless you don't compile it on your own it depends on the package maintainer of your distribution.

For all MySQL programs you can find out which file is read by calling it with `--help` option.
The mysqld (server) additionally requires the `--verbose` option.

```
$ mysqld --help --verbose
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html

> To determine whether a program reads option files, invoke it with the --help option. (For mysqld, use --verbose and --help.) If the program reads option files, the help message indicates which files it looks for and which option groups it recognizes.

Answer (score 0):

I only have the /etc/my.cnf file, so I guess this is the default location.

Comment: On my CentOS 5.2 Installed MySQL 5.6 but doesn't show my.cnf at neither location. Do you have any idea about that?